# How to calculate cohen's d in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, statistics

I need to calculate [cohen's d](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size#Cohen.27s_d) to determine the effect size of an experiment. Is there any implementation in a sound library I could use? If not, what would be a good implementation?

Comment: I find it curious that you asked a question and answered it immediately...

Comment: I do that on a regular basis and [it's OK](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). I have found an answer myself but I suspect others may be able to provide better ones. So let the votes determine which one that is.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since Python3.4, you can use the [`statistics` module](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/statistics.html) for calculating spread and average metrics. With that, Cohen's d can be calculated easily:

```
from statistics import mean, stdev
from math import sqrt

# test conditions
c0 = [2, 4, 7, 3, 7, 35, 8, 9]
c1 = [i * 2 for i in c0]

cohens_d = (mean(c0) - mean(c1)) / (sqrt((stdev(c0) ** 2 + stdev(c1) ** 2) / 2))

print(cohens_d)
```

Output:

```
-0.5567679522645598
```

So we observe a medium effect.

Answer (score 27):

The above implementation is correct in the special case that the two groups have equal size. A more general solution based on the formulas found at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size) and in [Robert Coe's article](http://www.leeds.ac.uk/educol/documents/00002182.htm) is the 2nd method shown below. Be aware that the denominator is the pooled standard deviation which is generally only appropriate if the population standard deviation is equal for both groups:

```
from numpy import std, mean, sqrt

#correct if the population S.D. is expected to be equal for the two groups.
def cohen_d(x,y):
    nx = len(x)
    ny = len(y)
    dof = nx + ny - 2
    return (mean(x) - mean(y)) / sqrt(((nx-1)*std(x, ddof=1) ** 2 + (ny-1)*std(y, ddof=1) ** 2) / dof)

#dummy data
x = [2,4,7,3,7,35,8,9]
y = [i*2 for i in x]
# extra element so that two group sizes are not equal.
x.append(10)

#correct only if nx=ny
d = (mean(x) - mean(y)) / sqrt((std(x, ddof=1) ** 2 + std(y, ddof=1) ** 2) / 2.0)
print ("d by the 1st method = " + str(d))
if (len(x) != len(y)):
    print("The first method is incorrect because nx is not equal to ny.")

#correct for more general case including nx !=ny
print ("d by the more general 2nd method = " + str(cohen_d(x,y)))
```

Output will be:

d by the 1st method = -0.559662109472
The first method is incorrect because nx is not equal to ny.
d by the more general 2nd method = -0.572015604666

Comment: It appears to me that ztest_ind from statsmodels could also be used but I have no experience with it.

Comment: I think this is an important contribution - however, in this example, the first and the second method should yield the same result, right?

Comment: No, because nx = 9 and ny=8. Note the x.append(10) line.

Comment: @skynaut its a quite old post but, I have a small question. How the formula should be updated if the standart deviations are not same ? And also, by *same* do you mean exactly the same or similar ?

Comment: @zwlayer in this case you could use the Cohen’s d for Welch test

Comment: I think it is worth noting that this correction is called Hedge's g

Answer (score 5):

In Python 2.7, you can use `numpy` with a couple of caveats, as I discovered while adapting Bengt's answer from Python 3.4.

1. Ensure division always returns float with: `from __future__ import division`
2. Specify the division argument on the variance with `ddof=1` into the `std` function , i.e. `numpy.std(c0, ddof=1)`. numpy's standard deviation default behaviour is to divide by `n`, whereas with `ddof=1` it will divide by `n-1`.

Code

```
from __future__ import division #Ensure division returns float
from numpy import mean, std # version >= 1.7.1
from math import sqrt
import sys
        

def cohen_d(x,y):
        return (mean(x) - mean(y)) / sqrt((std(x, ddof=1) ** 2 + std(y, ddof=1) ** 2) / 2.0)

if __name__ == "__main__":                
        # test conditions
        c0 = [2, 4, 7, 3, 7, 35, 8, 9]
        c1 = [i * 2 for i in c0]
        print(cohen_d(c0,c1))
```

Output will then be:

```
-0.556767952265
```

Comment: Thanks for the backport! Why do you require numpy to be no younger than 1.9.1?

Comment: @Bengt Simply that the `std` function exists with the `ddof` argument and the requirement to override the default value with '-1' in versions 1.7.1 and the current 1.9.1.

Comment: So you are just being careful to require a version you know will work and there is no concrete reason to assume a later version will break this behavior.

Comment: I don't understand why here you specify a formula that only works when both groups have same size. You could have specified the general formula.

Comment: @Maciek Please specify your constructive recommendation to improve this answer. Note: this answer is *an adaptation of another answer*; as has clearly been stated. I recommend you submit a improved solution and allow people to upvote your work.

Comment: @pds no need to do that, see the response by kelkka. It depends on pandas, but one can trivially modify it and use for pure numpy

Answer (score 2):

If anyone has trouble with any of the above answers, I've written a function for Python 3.7 that takes a Pandas Series and returns Cohen's d:

```
from numpy import var, mean, sqrt
from pandas import Series

def cohend(d1: Series, d2: Series) -> float:

    # calculate the size of samples
    n1, n2 = len(d1), len(d2)

    # calculate the variance of the samples
    s1, s2 = var(d1, ddof=1), var(d2, ddof=1)

    # calculate the pooled standard deviation
    s = sqrt(((n1 - 1) * s1 + (n2 - 1) * s2) / (n1 + n2 - 2))

    # calculate the means of the samples
    u1, u2 = mean(d1), mean(d2)

    # return the effect size
    return (u1 - u2) / s
```